# Find and remove loops in a Linked list

Tags: c, data-structures

Below I have written a program to detect and and remove a loop from list using C. I am getting a runtime error, but I am not able to find it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//node definition
struct node {
    int key;
    struct node *next;
};

// This function will make a new node
struct node *newNode(int key) {
    struct node *temp = (struct node*)(malloc)(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->key = key;
    temp->next = NULL;
}

//This function will detect and remove a loop from linked list
void detect(struct node *head) {
    struct node *slow = head;
    struct node *fast = head->next;

    while (fast && fast->next) {
        if (slow == fast)
            break;
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next->next;
    }
    if (slow == fast) {
        slow = head;
        while (slow != fast->next) {
            slow = slow->next;
            fast = fast->next;
        }
        fast->next = NULL;
    }
}

//This function will print list
void print(struct node *head) {
    struct node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", temp->key);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
} 

//This function is driver method
int main() {
    struct node *head = newNode(10);
    head->next = newNode(20);
    head->next->next = newNode(30);
    head->next->next->next = newNode(40);
    head->next->next->next->next = newNode(50);
    head->next->next->next->next->next = head->next->next;
    detect(head);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your function newNode does not return anything. You should add `return temp` at the end of the function.

Comment: Thanks, Laurent H. It Worked. :)

Comment: My answer can be accepted then ?

Answer (score 2):

The function newNode does not return anything, which is not consistent with the prototype.
Looking at your code, you should add `return temp` at the end of the function.

Comment: Teach a man to fish: tell the OP how to get useful warnings to avoid silly mistakes: `gcc -Wall -Wextra` or `clang -Weverything`